# Apache Airflow: where to store downloaded files between operators execution?

Tags: airflow

I started building a data processing pipeline with Apache Airflow and stuck with (possibly)
very basic problem: where to store files downloaded by `operator1` and then has to be processed by `operator2`?

`operator1` - BashOperator to download zip file from an external resource. I do this with `curl` to be able to retry or restart downloading because external resources are flaky.

`operator2` - airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_wasb operator to upload to Azure Blob

So the question is how `operator2` can access files downloaded by `operator1`?
Should `operator1` upload files somewhere or it is possible to delegate this to next task?

```
operator1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='download_ds_archive',
    bash_command="curl --retry 10 -O -C - https://extresource/file.zip",
    xcom_push=True,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

operator2 = FileToWasbOperator(
    task_id='stage_xml_files_to_azure_blob',
    ...
)

operator1 >> operator2
```

Comment: If you are using `CeleryExecutor` (where your tasks can possibly run on different physical machines), then indeed you'll have to either keep your file on a shared storage such as NFS / common EBS volume mounted across all nodes. Otherwise (if you don't want to do that), then you'll have to combine both downloading and processing tasks into one using a `PythonOperator` or a custom operator (with the obvious downside that processing failure would mean that file will be have to downloaded again).

Comment: `.."Should operator1 upload files somewhere"..` there's little merit in it unless (1) downloading files from that "somewhere" is cheaper than downloading from "external resource" (2) you have to use this file in more than one tasks

Comment: I use LocalExecutor and think that a custom operator might be an option. Thanks!